# Where are these Django log messages disappearing to?

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm running the Django 1.54 shell:

```
% python ~/predictstat/manage.py shell
>>> import django
>>> django.get_version()
'1.5.4'
```

Then I setup the logging:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Then I show you the logging configuration:

```
 >>> from django.conf import settings
 >>> settings.LOGGING
 {'handlers': {'file': {'level': 'DEBUG', 'interval': 1, 'when': 'midnight', 'filename': 'logs/myApp.log', 'formatter': 'verbose', 'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler'}}, 'loggers': {'myApp': {'level': 'DEBUG', 'handlers': ['file']}, 'django': {'level': 'DEBUG', 'propagate': True, 'handlers': ['file']}}, 'version': 1, 'disable_existing_loggers': False, 'formatters': {'simple': {'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'}, 'verbose': {'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', 'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s'}}}
```

Then I print a log message:

```
>>> logger.info("Hello World")
```

But this log message is not showing up in any file or anywhere else as far as I can tell. Certainly not in logs/myApp.log.

Can someone tell me where these log messages are vanishing to? Why won't this logging work?

Answer (score 0):

It is not getting handled by any handler, that is why it is not getting logged anywhere. Your settings has handlers defined for two loggers defined: `myApp` and `django`.

But you are getting a logger named `__main__` which is the value of `__name__` in the shell. I suggest trying these lines:

```
>>> logger = logging.getLogger("myApp")
>>> logger.info("My Test line")
```

Now you should see it in your log file.

Answer (score 0):

In the python shell `__name__` will eval to "**main**", and you have no logger configured for this name and no config for the root logger neither. Also using a file logger you should use an absolute path - but using a file logger in a potentially multiprocess setup is not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Call `logging.basicConfig` first.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='debug.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.debug('Dig this, I\'m printing.')
```

Refer to the [Logging Cookbook](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-logging-in-multiple-modules) for a more advanced example, which shows how to log to both the console and a file simultaneously and formatting the logger's output, even across different modules.

Comment: Django takes care of configuring the loggers based on the settings so no need to call basicConfig.

Comment: Ah, I see. It definitely looked like a general `logging` module issue, but after reading the [Django logging docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) I'm sure you're right.